# Non uniform image cropping in android

Tags: android, image, crop

I am using android's inbuilt image cropping functionality.But i need my images to be cropped non uniformly, unlike Android's cropping method.In that method,while we expand any of the side(left,right,top or bottom), the corresponding opposite side too will get expanded.I don't want such a cropping.I need crisp cropping in the specific direction only,while other sides stay non changeable.